# Unable to create folder inside blob container using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to  to create a folder inside a blob storage container in Azure using terraform but it is failing as below. Any work around to achieve this ? Create a empty folder or a folder inside a blob storage container with a dummy file just to achieve the folder creation.

```js
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  version  = ">=1.31"
  }
  
  resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "test" {
  name                   = "test/1.txt              "
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.azstg-rg.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.stor-cont.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "./1.txt"

}
```

The script executes successfully however I am not able to view the folder and dont think it was successful.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: You can add permission to view the content of the blob ( In case you are the owner), click on `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> Fill the relevant data -> Click save

Comment: The logged in user is having contributor access to the subscription already. Looks like it is creating a corrupted folder.

Comment: I can reproduce this error. Does it solve your question?

Comment: No.The error is still there. Looks like the folder is not getting created properly

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-access-blobs-queues-portal), please note that,

> When you access blob or queue data using the Azure portal, the portal
> makes requests to Azure Storage under the covers. A request to Azure
> Storage can be authorized using either your **Azure AD account** or the
> **storage account access key**. The portal indicates which method you are
> using, and enables you to switch between the two if you have the
> appropriate permissions.

In this case, you can check [the current authentication method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-access-blobs-queues-portal#determine-the-current-authentication-method) when you view the folder. If you are authenticating using your Azure AD account, you need to [grant RBAC roles for blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal#rbac-roles-for-blobs-and-queues) to the logged in user. In addition, ensure that you does not have set any `network_rules` in the storage account level to restrict this request.

**Edit**

I can reproduce this error with the following code. By default, you will access the blobs with storage account access key authentication when your logged in user is having **contributor** role access to the subscription already.

You can select the `change access level` to `container(anonymous read access for containers and blobs)` via clicking `...` at right side of your container name. Then refresh your web browser and re-check your data blob. Then you can change `change access level` back to `private`. If you can not do this in the UI, try to change the `authentication method` to using `Azure AD account`, after finished the above then change it back to using `access key`.

[image]